# Filtering multiple request parameters

Tags: php, laravel

This is pretty straightforward, it takes requests from the frontend, checking if it is present on the request, if it does, an action is taken for that if statement.

I wonder if there is a way to remove some if statements or make it less complicated.

```
private function applyFiltering($query, $request)
{
    if ($request->has('active_group')) {
        $query->whereNotIn('status_id', [1, 6, 4]);
        $query->whereHas('userStatus', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->whereNotIn('status_id', [1, 6, 4]);
        });
    }

    if ($request->has('waiting_group')) {
       $query->whereNotIn('status_id', [1, 6]);
        $query->whereHas('userStatus', function ($query) use ($request) {
              $query->where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->whereNotIn('status_id', [1, 6])->where('status_id',4);
         });
    }


    if ($request->has('meeting_group')) {
        $query->where('type_id', 2);
    }

    if ($request->has('comp_meeting_group')) {
        $query->where('type_id', 4);
    }

    if ($request->has('completed_group')) {
            $query->whereHas('userStatus', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->where('status_id', 1);
            });
    }

    if ($request->has('canceled_group')) {
        $query->whereHas('userStatus', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->where('status_id', 6);
        });
    }


    if ($request->has('shift_group')) {
        $query->where('status_id', 1)->where('type_id', 6);
    }

    if ($request->has('announce_group')) {
        $query->where('type_id', 3);
    }

    if ($request->has('task_id')) {
        $query->where('id', 'like', '%' . $request->input('task_id') . '%');
    }

    if ($request->has('task_statuses')) {
        $statuses = $request->input('task_statuses');
        $query->whereIn('status_id', $statuses);
    }
    if ($request->has('task_types')) {
        $statuses = $request->input('task_types');
        $query->whereIn('type_id', $statuses);
    }
    if ($request->has('task_priorities')) {
        $statuses = $request->input('task_priorities');
        $query->whereIn('priority_id', $statuses);
    }
    if ($request->has('task_invite_users')) {
        $toUsers = $request->input('task_invite_users');
        $query->whereHas('taskAssignment', function ($query) use ($request, $toUsers) {
            $query->whereIn('assigned_to', $toUsers);
        });

        // $query->whereIn('to_user_id',$statuses);
    }

    if ($request->has('task_users')) {
        $byUsers = $request->input('task_users');
        $query->whereHas('taskAssignment', function ($query) use ($request, $byUsers) {
            $query->whereIn('assigned_by', $byUsers);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are those sections mutually exclusive or can a request have multiple of those?

Comment: @Mast they are exclusive.

Comment: Then shouldn't you be using `if...else if` ?

Comment: @MD.TabishMahfuz At least, with a bit of magic a switch could work too, or a foreach over an array with the supported content.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

````
private function applyFiltering($query, $request)
{

    $query->when($request->has('active_group'), function($query) use($request) {
        $query->whereNotIn('status_id', [1, 6, 4]);
        $query->whereHas('userStatus', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->whereNotIn('status_id', [1, 6, 4]);
        });
    })->when($request->has('waiting_group'), function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereNotIn('status_id', [1, 6]);
        $query->whereHas('userStatus', function ($query) use ($request) {
              $query->where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->whereNotIn('status_id', [1, 6])->where('status_id',4);
         });
    })
    ........
    ........
    ........
}
```
````

Comment: While this technically removes the `if` statements, I'm not sure this looks any better than the original.

Comment: Any callable should be able to be passed into `Builder::when()` so the filters could be moved to another class / separate private functions.